# javascript can't accept in output rewrite in views

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, view

I need to display the node title,node edit and node url.when user hits the node url means its open in popup window so for that i try to rewrite the output of that url field in views.First i create a new js file called popup.js  include to via theme.info inside that file i paste the following code

```
      function popUp(URL) {
      day = new Date();
      id = day.getTime();
     eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=250,left = 12,top = 259');");
```

Then i move to output rewrite section add following code

```
     <A HREF="javascript:popUp('[url]')">view</A>
```

But that url not open pop up window.is there any thing i missed.Any one point me my error.

thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your js file

```
function popUp(URL) {
     var  day = new Date();
     var  id = day.getTime();
     window.open(URL);
}
```

if it doesn't work then try to put the same code in you page.tpl.php file. Also try with chang the name of your callback form popUp() to other name. It may be conflicting with other callback.